# Speeding up perl DBI fetchrow_hashref

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, perl

I have something that looks like this:

```
my $report = new ReportGenerator; #custom object
my $dbh = $dbc->prepare('SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_condition'); #DBI handle
$dbh->execute();
while(my $href = $dbh->fetchrow_hashref){
    $report->process_record($href);
}
$dbh->finish();
print $report->printReport();
```

My problem is that each iteration of the loop is very slow. The problem is the MySQL. I was wondering if it was possible to put some kind of wrapper in the while loop to make it fetch more than one record at a time, at the same time, fetching all records into memory is not practical either. I am not worried about the efficiency of the code(hashref vs arrayref,etc..). Rather, I am interested in fetching lets say 10000 records at a time.

The database has ~5 Million records. I can not change/upgrade the server.

Thanks

Comment: That code should run quickly enough.  Are you sure that the select does not take a long time to run?  You might want to time how long the execute takes.  And of course, your process could be slow.  You might try timing just the fetch without the process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the fetchall_arrayref function which accepts a 'maxrows' argument:

```
while (my $data = $dbc->fetchall_arrayref(undef, 10000)) {
  for my $row( @{$data} ) {
    $report->process_record($row);
  }
}
```

You could also look at the [RowCacheSize](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#RowCacheSize) property which attempts to control how many records are returned in a fetch from your driver.

Comment: fetchall_arrayref isn't recommended when you're simply processing records one at a time and discarding them. That's because it has to make lots of memory allocations to store all the fields of all the rows, and memory allocations are expensive. See page 22 of http://www.slideshare.net/Tim.Bunce/dbi-advanced-tutorial-2007

Answer (score 4):

Which bit is slow? Is it the call to `execute`, `fetchrow_hashref` or `process_record`? It seems unlikely to me that `fetchrow_hashref` is the problem. It's far more likely to be the execution of the query or the black-box of `process_record`.

But this all guesswork. It's impossible to really help here. I recommend you get some real data about the performance of the code by using [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/release/Devel-NYTProf).

Comment: I was allready doing that and found the problem to be unrelated to this question, that said both methods are fairly close to each other. 221sec vs 239 sec. So still there is a slight improvement. although I found an interesting bottleneck in a hash lookup. I have a function that checks if the hash exists, if it does it gets a value, and if it dosent, it pulls it from mysql. with an average of avg 4µs/call. the problem is that the function gets called 15 million times. which is almost 1 minute. but that isnt something that can be fixed easiily.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to fetch rows as hashes using the DBI is to use `bind_columns()` like this:

```
  $sth->execute;
  my %row;
  $sth->bind_columns( \( @row{ @{$sth->{NAME_lc} } } ));
  while ($sth->fetch) {
      print "$row{region}: $row{sales}\n";
  }
```

That's only appropriate if you're happy for each row to reuse the same hash.

Beyond that, I agree with davorg, avoid guesswork: measure first.

For much more information on using the DBI, including performance, see my [tutorial slides](http://www.slideshare.net/Tim.Bunce/dbi-advanced-tutorial-2007) (from 2007, but still relevant).